# Removing an object from an array if it exists in the array already (Otherwise add it)

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

I have a set of checkboxes - which the user ticks on.  The checkboxes pass some data an id and a name that i need later on for sorting.  Because two objects are not equal even though they contain the same values I cant use Array.includes.

Here is an example of the data

```
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "age_group_ids"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "age_group_ids"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "earnings_group_ids"
  },
 {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "earnings_group_ids"
  },

]
```

This is the current function (which would work if the items were not objects

```
const submitFilterDetails = (value) => {
  return async (dispatch,getState) => {
    const currentArray = (getState().filter.filtersArray);

    if(!currentArray.includes(value)) {
      dispatch(addToFiltersArray(value))
    } else {
      dispatch(removeFromFiltersArray(value));
    }

  }
}
```

How can you sort this so I only have unique values

Comment: Try with [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find :

```
YourArray.find(obj => obj.id == value.id && obj.name == value.name);
```

Comment: Used this to find the item then remove that item if it existed

Answer (score 0):

```
const src = [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "age_group_ids"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "age_group_ids"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "earnings_group_ids"
  },

]

const out = src.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.some(i => i.id === curr.id) ? acc : acc.concat([curr]) , [])
// the `out` variable has 2 unique items
```